# Google Street View time-machine (historic imagery) not showing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I would like to include the Google Street View historic imagery on an embedded frame I am working on. The problem is that I see no way on the APi to include this imagery...it comes standard in the Google Maps ( [see here](https://www.google.com/maps/@39.5096624,-0.4124261,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s7xJmy9KDMsnScyMws0GCmw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) the "clock icon"on the top left corner ) but the same thing on the google street view panorama that I am embedding on my HTML does not show up.... [link to my html test](http://www.openforis.org/fileadmin/installer/StreetViewTest.html)

Does anybody know how to specify that you want to be able to access the historical imagery??

Thanks!

Comment: This is how the address box looks in my application [see here](http://i.imgur.com/Ck0HdLd.png) and how it actually looks in street view in Google Maps [see this other pic](http://i.imgur.com/0TsBDXz.png)